# Issue with Schedulable implementation and Callout

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, callout

I am receiving an error message when trying to test a class that implements Schedulable.

```
System.CalloutException: Callout from scheduled Apex not supported.
```

People have suggested using the `@future` method, but I am worried about my application being out of sync. I am using a callout to synchronize a Salesforce object to another system and then update the Salesforce object with the ID from the other system. My though is that the `@future` method may prevent that from happening in a linear fashion (SOQL to get sObject, Callout to create and get the ID from other system, Update sObject with ID).

I have looked at using a `Database.Batchable` interface but am a bit lost. All I need the batch to do is the following.

```
bigClass sync = new bigClass();
sync.init();
```

Batchable's execute method appears to require a List. Is there any way to have it just run the init method?

Comment: what 'launches' the schedulable class?  What kind of object (business purpose) requires the sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this will work (assuming that you don't need to schedule back to back callouts as you can only have one Queueable Callout running at a time)

```
public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        //Do your 
        //SOQL to get sObject, 
        //Callout to create and get the ID from other system, 
        //Update sObject with ID
        //It can all happen in this one method.
    }
}
```

In your scheduled class, just instantiate the above Class and execute it!

```
public class ScheduledClass implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        System.enqueueJob(new AsyncExecutionExample());
    }
}
```

I think that's all you have to do.

Comment: Awesome! Code Coverage tests ran and it seems like it will work! Now to move to production and make sure. Definitely adds a layer of complexity... You'd think Salesforce would just allow the Schedulable Interface to be run asynchronously and allow callouts, but I digress. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a pain eh. However, compared to what you have to do to implement a batchable version, it's a lot cleaner :)

Comment: And wouldn't you know it! There is a known issue with Queueable and Mock Callouts - they're tripping the callout loop detector on unit tests. Our Sandbox is API version 36 so I didn't catch it until I created a Change Set. Oh well... Now to wait until next Saturday. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000sXtbAAE

Comment: Lucky the fix is coming so soon! Still, next Saturday is going to FEEL like a way off...